# InputStream is = conn.getInputStream() doesn't get Datastream --> App-crash

Tags: java, android, webrequest

This is a code from Digi Device Cloud slightly modified. I don't get any `Inputstream`, so my App crash. I'm trying to display the data from Digi Device on my Android App. Trying to debug it the App work smoothly until it get to

`InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();`.

I get in Debugger:

`com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpUrlConnectionDelegate:https://devicecloud.digi.com/ws/DataStream/00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF60FE08/xbee.serialIn`. After this line it jumps directly to `catch (Exception e)`.

Looking in `getInputStream()` it seems like it don't get override. I already searched here because of this problem, but couldn't find a solution, maybe I just overlooked something.

```
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    throw new UnknownServiceException("Does not support writing to the input stream");
}
```

Here is the code:

```
public class InputXML extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView view_xml;
    private String encodedAuthorization,responseContent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_input_xml);

        XMLreference();
        String request = getRequest().toString();
        view_xml.setText(request);

    }

        /**
         * Run the web service request
         */
        public String getRequest() {
            HttpsURLConnection conn = null;

            final String username = "username"; // put your Device Cloud username here
            final String password = "password"; // put your Device Cloud password here

            try {
                // Create url to the Device Cloud server for a given web service request
                URL url = new URL("https://devicecloud.digi.com/ws/DataStream/00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF60FE08/xbee.serialIn");
                conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                // Build authentication string
                String userpassword = username + ":" + password;

                // can change this to use a different base64 encoder
                // String encodedAuthorization =  Base64.encodeBase64String(userpassword.getBytes()).trim();
                byte[] data = null;
                try {
                    data = userpassword.getBytes("UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                encodedAuthorization = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT).trim();


                // set request headers
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "
                        + encodedAuthorization);
                // Get input stream from response and convert to String
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                Scanner isScanner = new Scanner(is);
                StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                while (isScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    buf.append(isScanner.nextLine() + "\n");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"in while schleife",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
                responseContent = buf.toString();

                // add line returns between tags to make it a bit more readable
                responseContent = responseContent.replaceAll("><", ">\n<");
                //responseContent = "Es übergibt weiter";

                // Output response to standard out
                System.out.println(responseContent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Print any exceptions that occur
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.disconnect();
            }
            return responseContent;
        }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_input_xml, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void XMLreference(){
        view_xml = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_xml);
    }
}
```

If it helps, here is the **original code**:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

/* Can replace this with any base 64 encoder for basic authentication. For java 6 
 * installations on Sun's JRE you can use "sun.misc.BASE64Encoder" however this will 
 * not work in some installations (using OpenJDK).  Java mail 
 * (javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility) also contains a Base 64 encoder in Java 6.  A 
 * public domain version exists at http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/
 */
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

/**
 * This is a stub class with a main method to run a Device Cloud web service.
 */
public class WebServiceRequest {
    private static final String username = "username"; // put your Device Cloud username here
    private static final String password = "password"; // put your Device Cloud password here

    /**
     * Run the web service request
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpsURLConnection conn = null;

        try {
            // Create url to the Device Cloud server for a given web service request
            URL url = new URL("https://devicecloud.digi.com/ws/DataStream/00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF60FE08/xbee.serialIn");
            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET"); 

            // Build authentication string
            String userpassword = username + ":" + password;

            // can change this to use a different base64 encoder
            String encodedAuthorization = Base64.encodeBase64String(userpassword.getBytes()).trim();

            // set request headers
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "
                    + encodedAuthorization);
// Get input stream from response and convert to String
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            Scanner isScanner = new Scanner(is);
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            while (isScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                buf.append(isScanner.nextLine() + "\n");
            }
            String responseContent = buf.toString();

            // add line returns between tags to make it a bit more readable
            responseContent = responseContent.replaceAll("><", ">\n<");

            // Output response to standard out
            System.out.println(responseContent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Print any exceptions that occur
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform Http operations in main thread! you should do that on a separate thread and pass the result to the main thread.

Comment: You mean creating a new class and get in the main my contructor to call the result? Well I already tried this, but it didn't work either.

Comment: No, see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog

Comment: Thanks I will read it now. I hope my english and programming skills are good enough to understand it.